# Assign multiple const variables in single declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm rather new to react/JS therefore this question my sound somehow dumb:

I need multiple variables that are set depending on a location(System variable). Those variables should be constants as they should never change for a given instance.

This is my current solution, it works but it feels very wrong  to define variables inside other variable declarations. It also seems to not be possible to declare footerWidth and footerAltText as constants without an initial value.

```
 <Box
    as='img'
    width={footerWidth}
    justifyContent='center'
    alignContent='center'
    src={footerLogoSource}
    alt={footerAltText}
 />
```

Those attributes are provided by my features.ts:

```
export let footerWidth: string
export let footerAltText: string
export const footerLogoSource: string =
  getAppConfig().contextPath +
  (() => {
    switch (getAppConfig().landesvariante) {
      case Variante.SN:
        footerWidth = '30%'
        footerAltText = 'lorem ipsum'
        return '/assets/kofin_eu_logo.svg'
      case Variante.BB:
        footerWidth = '20%'
        footerAltText = 'lorem ipsum 2'
        return '/assets/logo_bb.svg'
      default:
        return null
    }
  })()
```

One solution would be to make 3 switch-case configurations for the 3 variables, but that would lead to alot of duplicated code...

**Is there a proper way to do this?**

Comment: You can just return an object.  -> `return {url: '/assets/logo_bb.svg', footerWidth: '20%', footerAltText: 'lorem ipsum 2'}`

Comment: ... and then destructure that object into the `const` declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const [footerWidth, footerAltText, footerLogoSource] = (() => {
  const config = getAppConfig();

  switch (config.landesvariante) {
    case Variante.SN:
      return ['30%', 'lorem ipsum', `${config.contextPath}/assets/kofin_eu_logo.svg`];
    case Variante.BB:
      return ['20%', 'lorem ipsum 2', `${config.contextPath}/assets/logo_bb.svg`];
    default:
      return [undefined, undefined, null];
  }
})();
```

You can use object destructuring as well

```js
const { width: footerWidth, altText: footerAltText, logo: footerLogoSource } = (() => {
  const config = getAppConfig();
  switch (config.landesvariante) {
    case Variante.SN:
      return {
        width: '30%',
        altText: 'lorem ipsum',
        logo: `${config.contextPath}/assets/kofin_eu_logo.svg`
      };
    case Variante.BB:
      return {
        width: '20%',
        altText: 'lorem ipsum 2',
        logo: `${config.contextPath}/assets/logo_bb.svg`
      };
    default:
      return {logo: null};
  }
})();
```

Comment: Array destructuring is fine for a couple of attributes, but can get unwieldy quickly.    The OP is also using TS, so switching to object destructuring will gain some nice code completion here.

Comment: Adding object destructing approach to the answer.

Comment: Thanks alot @AbitoPrakash and Keith. This solution was exactly what i was looking for.
Seems like i'll go and learn more about the whole object/array destructuring concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without any destructering or self invoking functions and with some additional typing

```
enum Variante {
  SN,
  BB
}

interface IConfig {
  footerWidth: string;
  footerAltText: string;
  footerLogoSource: string;
}

type AppConfig = {
  [key in Variante]: IConfig;
};

const config: AppConfig = {
  [Variante.BB]: {
    footerWidth: "30%",
    footerAltText: "lorem ipsum",
    footerLogoSource: "lorem ipsum"
  },
  [Variante.SN]: {
    footerWidth: "20%",
    footerAltText: "lorem ipsum",
    footerLogoSource: "lorem ipsum"
  }
};

export default config[getAppConfig().landesvariante as keyof typeof Variante];
```

Comment: Thanks you for the help. Sadly this solution would lead to other problems/inconveniences in our codebase. I'll still try it out to learn more about your approach!